# More than two variables in a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I need some information regarding whether or not we can put more than two variable in a foreach loop. Do keep in mind I'm still a complete newbie :D

For example, I'm getting the data of the variable from a database with comma's

```
<?php
while($segment = $results->fetchRow()) {
    $seg = explode(',', $segment['name']);
    $section = explode(',', $segment['sek_id']);
    $array = array_combine($seg, $section);
    foreach($array as $out => $key){
        if($out != ""){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $out; ?></option>
```

and here I managed to put two variables into my foreach loop.

Is there any way with it while still using a foreach loop? Like maybe if I have an 'id=""' where I would put the id's that is in comma's in it?

Comment: it is `$key => $out`

Comment: I don't exactly see what your problems is? Also you probably don't want to save comma separated values inside your database.

Comment: @MateiMihai Is there any difference in doing a different one compared to the usual?

Comment: @Rizier123 Can you give me some thoughts/explanation on why shouldn't I use comma's in my database? Is there any drawback or something?

Comment: If you have 2 pieces of data then you would usually store them in 2 database fields, not 1 database field separated by commas. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following way.

```
<?php

    $results =  $results->fetchRow();

    foreach($results as $result)
    {
          if(!empty($result['name']))
          {
          ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $result['sek_id']; ?>">
             <?php echo $result['name']; ?>
         </option>

    <?php
          }
    }
<?php
```

That will be great if you can provide result of `$results->fetchRow();`

Let me know in case of any query.